# SNMP: How to monitor devices that do not have static IP adress with Zabbix

Tags: dhcp, snmp, zabbix, dynamic-ip

I have some equipments in my LAN but the way things are working; I cannot set statics IPs for them, they really need to have DHCP enabled.

I am using Zabbix, and for host configuration, the Ip address is required; is there any way to go around this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set Zabbix to connect to DNS in your host config:

[image]